# File -> Duplicate crashing NSDocument-based app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a document-based OSX app.  I recently found that using Duplicate crashes my application, the debugger stops in native assembly.

I have an NSDocument subclass that overrides these:

```
- (NSData *)dataRepresentationOfType:(NSString *)typeName
- (BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper
                     ofType:(NSString *)typeName
                      error:(NSError **)outError
```

I can save and open and if I add save-as to the file menu I can even save-as.

If I do this…

```
- (NSDocument *)duplicateAndReturnError:(NSError **)outError
{
    return [[Document alloc] init];
}
```

…it no longer crashes, but Duplicate then does nothing, no animation, no new window, nothing.

Sorry, I know that's not much to go on, but I don't know how to debug this.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The documentation indicates you need to do something quite different.

Comment: Thanks that was just the nudge in the right direction I needed.  I changed to use

    - (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError

And the problem went away.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Although the original poster figured it out, to be clear to anyone reading this in the future: You should implement *one of* the three `read` methods and a *matching* `write` method.

Eg, pick which set of methods you want to implement from the following three choices:

// with this pair you’re in charge of reading and writing everything yourself, your on-disk format could be anything at all
open func read(from url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws
open func write(to url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws

// with this pair you deal with a FileWrapper, which makes life a bit easier if your file format is a bundle (folder with an extension)
open func read(from fileWrapper: FileWrapper, ofType typeName: String) throws
open func fileWrapper(ofType typeName: String) throws -> FileWrapper

// with this pair you just are reading writing a single flat binary file
open func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws
open func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data